# Open file by URL from WPF

Tags: c#, .net, process

I would like to programmatically open a document from a SharePoint URL.

I have the following code:

```
Process wordProcess = new Process();
wordProcess.StartInfo.FileName 
    = "http://sharepoint/blank_site_1/document library 1/word document.docx";
wordProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
wordProcess.Start();
```

This opens a webbrowser window and downloads the file, which is not what I want.  If I append

```
wordProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "OpenAsReadOnly"
```

as per ([the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo.aspx)) I get a Win32 Exception "The parameter is incorrect" at `wordProcess.Start()`, despite the verb being present in `wordProcess.StartInfo.Verbs` when examining in the debugger.

I have a POC which does this by extracting the default program from the registry, building a command and starting the program with the filename, but I'd rather not go down that route if this can be easily solved, as all I want to do is open a file (the path of which just happens to look like a URL) with the default program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, try this:

```
wordProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "winword.exe";
wordProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"http://sharepoint/blank_site_1/document_library_1/word document file.docx\"";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Specifying winword.exe is what I want to avoid - I just want to open the document (which happens to be at a URL) with the default program that is not a web-browser.  I'm starting to think that it might be impossible.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you specify a URL, the default app is the browser. Anyway, if Word is installed, then it's on the PATH, so you don't have to know exactly where winword.exe is on the user's machine.

Comment: Ah I thought so.  That is a shame.  Thanks for your time.  I edited your answer to include the quotes around the arguments, which are apparently necessary.